# which and find not working to locate ruby.exe path

Tags: find, which

From the home directory
`which ruby.exe` & `find ruby.exe`
return "no such file or directory"
However, I'm able to execute .rb programs in rubymine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
which ruby
```

If you would also like to be told when certain commands are shell builtins, you can use this:

```
type ruby
```

In Unix like operating systems the filename **suffixes** which traditionally denote executable files on DOS and Windows such as `.exe`, `.com`, and `.bat` **do not apply**! Instead, file permissions bits are used to denote which files are executable.

Comment: It is worth noting that in Unix-likes the filename suffixes which traditionally apply to executable files on DOS and Windows such as `.exe`, `.com` do not apply.  There are file permissions bits to denote executable files (which might be or might be not binary executables, whereas Windows executables are always binary.)

Comment: @alex: +1.added.

Comment: It helped me. I was going crazy trying to find path of `scss` executable